# PayPal error for seller mail

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-sandbox

commerce and to use PayPal sandbox and I'm trying to do a simple transaction for testing the PayPal sandbox but i've an error that i can't to solve.

**This is my call to PayPal sandbox**:

```
$cmd='_xclick';
$busisness='SELLER MAIL';
$lc='IT';
$currency_code='EUR';
$no_note=0;
$bn=urlencode('PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest');
$return='localhost/PayPal/ok.php';
$cbt='Torna al MIO SITO';
$rm=2;
$item_name='prova prodotto 1';
$item_number='00000001';
$amount='22.50';
$url='https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webdescr'
        . '?cmd='.$cmd
        .'&busisness='.$busisness
        .'&lc='.$lc
        .'&currency_code='.$currency_code
        .'&no_note='.$no_note
        .'&bn='.$bn
        .'&return='.$return
        .'&cbt='.$cbt
        .'&rm='.$rm
        .'&item_name='.$item_name
        .'&item_number='.$item_number
        .'&amount='.$amount;
```

My problem is that receive this error:

**It isn't possible elaborate transaction because of a problem with the email address supplied by PayPal seller**

How can i fix it?

Thank's

Comment: You should put your email address where it says `$busisness='SELLER MAIL';`

Comment: This is not the issue, that was only a placeholder... The issue is that business is misspelt as busisness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelt the word `business`, you have put `busisness` but it should be `business`.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside